# detect process termination from task manager

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there anyway to detect when our process is going to get terminated from task manager?
and ideally know which process is about to terminate my process?

Thanks

Comment: Hard process termination isn't something that you can combat. When your process gets terminated with a call to [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) there's nothing you can do at that point, it's joever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to detect when our process is going to get terminated from task manager?

Typically, no.  If Task Manager knows your process has a UI, it may be nice and first send a `WM_CLOSE` or `WM_QUIT` message to your UI.  But, if your UI doesn't respond to that, or if the user tells TM to just kill your process, then TM resorts to brute force and there is no way to detect/react to that.  Your process is just gone immediately.

> ideally know which process is about to terminate my process?

The only way to do that (that I know of) is to manually hook the `TerminateProcess()` API in every running process, and communicate information about the caller back to your process before allowing the API to continue with its work.

Answer (score 1):

With registry settings (requires admin), you could subscribe to notifications via

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SilentProcessExit`

Note that 32-bit programs shall subscribe under `WOW6432Node` key:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SilentProcessExit`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/registry-entries-for-silent-process-exit